# GWT multiple modules. Specific case of reuse of existing components

Tags: gwt

Also if the multiple modules is something with a lot of thread i'm not finding something helping.

I have two modules, the second one inherit the first one because it uses client side components and is meant to be just a separate entry point for specific uses.
The second module naturally has his own html page pointing to the related compiled js but...not much surprise...when i start this second page, the onModuleLoad of both entry points is fired, first the first module because inherited and then the second one.

Problem: since the onModuleLoad, as suggested by tutorials and templates implements the page creation when i start the first module html page, it's all ok, but when i start the second module page i have the vertical "sum" of pages instead just my rendering.
I suppose i could set a session or process the address or use get parameters to avoid the inherit module renders the page but there's nothing wrong on this? what is the best strategy to reuse existing modules without render the related page?

update:

xml files looks both like

```
 <module rename-to="ModuleA">
     <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
     <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard" />
     <entry-point class="com.test.client.ModuleA" />
 </module>
```

and both onLoad method do page creation, something like

```
    rootPanel = RootPanel.get();
    rootPanel.setPixelSize(Window.getClientWidth(),  Window.getClientHeight());
    Label widget=new Label("hello");
    rootPanel.add(widget);
```

Edit:
To solve the problem I just created 3 modules instead of 2 : a core one that does nothing in unload and contains all the common part, a module A that render the first kind of page application and a module B that does another render in the unload. Such way no interference between A and B and since Core does no render in unload no problem at all

Comment: Right solution. You can post it as an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I just created 3 modules instead of 2 : a core one that does nothing in onload and contains all the common part, a module A that render the first kind of page application and a module B that does another render in the onload. Such way no interference between A and B and since Core does no render in onload no problem at all